# Heating Avocado

Tags: avocados

I was curious and looked for recipes containing avocados. I noticed there are hardly any recipes that contain heated or even cooked avocados, except for a few where avocado is put on a warm dish.

Does this have a specific reason? Does it get inedible when heated up?

Comment: I visited a "How Do You Roll?" restaurant recently, and they serve [baked stuffed avocados](http://howdoyouroll.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/stuffed_avo3.jpg).  Very yummy, quite edible.

Comment: Are they served warm?

Comment: Yes, they are served warm.

Comment: My mother decided to make toasted sandwich with avocado once. It was...interesting, to say the least. I can't recall the other fillings, but yeah, you may want to try a little first to see if you like it before continuing. It's not for everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're still edible after cooking, but they take on a texture people don't usually like too much. It's kinda similar to them being overripe, minus the browning, very soft and maybe even a little slimy. The flavor changes a bit too, but I'm not sure how to describe it. It may be subjective (I'm just completely used to eating them fresh) but it seems like they're definitely worse cooked. In any case, they don't need to be cooked, so why bother?

Note that you can heat them a bit without those effects, though, for example the brief cooking of quesadillas will leave them pretty much fresh.

Comment: Why bother cooking tomatoes, apples, and so on...

Comment: @MaxReid Because most people regard the result as delicious? With avocados, most people don't.

Comment: I didn't try it either, but I nobody I asked ever tried it. Maybe it IS delicious, too.

Comment: It's been tried. I've tried it. Like Jefromi says, it's just not good. You can get away with warming it on a sandwich or quesadilla, but it's better to add them cold at the end. They make good ice cream!

Comment: @MaxReid Don't worry, I understand why you asked the question. Your comment just made it sound like something was unclear about my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great selection of avocado recipies here:

http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/apr/26/avocado-recipes-10-best

The first one is all about baked avocado. It does go really mushy when you cook it - but I really like that.